# ввод данных в поле ввода окна tkinter, и вывод в базу аксесс

Tags: python, база-данных, tkinter

я пытаюсь автоматизировать прием заказов через питон и записывать их в аксесс но я не могу достать введенные в поле ввода параметры из функции и использовать их для заполнение строк в аксесс. Вот мой код:

```
import pyodbc

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("PythonGuides")
root.geometry('400x800')
root['bg'] = '#ffbf00'

def variable():
    pname = aydi.get()
    #print(pname)
    return pname


aydi = Entry(root)
aydi.pack(pady=30)
Button(
    root,
    text="Сохрани переменную",
    padx=10,
    pady=5,
    command=variable
).pack()
print(variable())
root.mainloop()

try:

    con_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' \
                 r'DBQ=C:\Users\krlls\awd\Рабочий стол\DataBase.accdb;'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)

    cursor = conn.cursor()



    number = 55512
    name = 1212
    age = 312


    myuser = (

        (number, name, age),

    )

    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?)', myuser)
    conn.commit()
    print('Data Inserted')


except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error in connection", e)
```

Comment: Вставку данных нужно делать в обработчике чего-то (например, у вас должна быть кнопка, при нажатии на которую данные записываются, в ее обработчике нажатия нужно выполнять вставку в базу). А не просто в конец файла добавлять код вставки в базу, и думать что все как-то магически заработает.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, надеюсь смогу это реализовать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099908/python-tkinter-return-value-from-function-used-in-command